# Unable to fetch Longitude and Latitude for user location

Tags: android, android-studio

Currently, my manifest.xml is set to following permissions for accessing location:

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
```

My mainActivity.java file has following code for LocationManager and requestLocationUpdates():

```
    locationmanager = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

    locationmanager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 2000, 10, locationlistener);
```

and @Override methods:

```
    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    this.location = location;
    longitude = location.getLongitude();
    latitude = location.getLatitude();
}
```

Code gives no errors. However, the result of the above code is 0.00 for both Longitude and Latitude.

PS: Only specific sections of code are picked up from the MainActivity file. Would be ready to edit the question if more details are required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that your `locationlistener` is defined as shown below. Add this class inside your `mainActivity.java`

```
class locationlistener implements LocationListener {


            @Override
            public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

                   //play with location

            }

            @Override
            public void onStatusChanged(String s, int i, Bundle bundle) {
                switch (i) {
                    case LocationProvider.AVAILABLE:
                        Log.i("LocationListener", "GPS Available");
                        break;
                    case LocationProvider.OUT_OF_SERVICE:
                        Log.e("LocationListener", "GPS Out Of Service");
                        break;
                    case LocationProvider.TEMPORARILY_UNAVAILABLE:
                        Log.w("LocationListener", "GPS Temporarily Unavailable");
                        break;
                    default:
                        Log.e("LocationListener", "Status changed");
                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onProviderEnabled(String s) {
                Log.e("Location", "Location was enabled");
            }

            @Override
            public void onProviderDisabled(String s) {
                Log.e("Location", "Location was disabled");
            }
        }
```